# Determining if Geocode falls within a Polygon/Series of Geocodes

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps, geocode

I have a series of geocodes for a pre-defined area/polygon that represents a sales region. For example:

```
-33.83585327701507, 151.2809005901216
-33.73335715102409, 150.8744770943904
-33.82163832733159, 150.8404448193081
-33.9974469167501, 151.247420749521
-33.83585327701507, 151.2809005901216
```

I then have a separate geocode that represents a location, e.g.:

```
-33.7984533, 151.1824504
```

I need to determine if the single location geocode falls within the pre-defined sales region/polygon. Is there an API or other method for programatically determining this? Couldn't see a Google Maps API for this so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That point (-33.7984533, 151.1824504), isn't in the polygon you provided.  To determine that with the Google Maps Javascript API v3, use the [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.containsLocation) method:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7984533, 151.1824504), polygon)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yqLvjf8z/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var polygonCoords = [{
      lat: -33.83585327701507,
      lng: 151.2809005901216
    },
    {
      lat: -33.73335715102409,
      lng: 150.8744770943904
    },
    {
      lat: -33.82163832733159,
      lng: 150.8404448193081
    },
    {
      lat: -33.9974469167501,
      lng: 151.247420749521
    },
    {
      lat: -33.83585327701507,
      lng: 151.2809005901216
    },
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    clickable: false
  });
  polygon.setMap(map);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon.getPath().getAt(i))
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7984533, 151.1824504)
  })
  console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7984533, 151.1824504), polygon));
  document.getElementById('contains').innerHTML = "containsLocation returns " + google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7984533, 151.1824504), polygon);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, polygon));
    document.getElementById('contains').innerHTML = "containsLocation returns " + google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, polygon);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="contains"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that information - very helpful. Do you know if there is an equivalent API/method to get the result without having to actually draw a map? For example I'd like to be able to pass in a JSON array of geocodes that represent the polygon area, and also pass in the geocode to check against and get a true/false result. I'm not explicitly needing to map the result, just determine if the geocode is inside/outside the polygon area.

Comment: There is no requirement to map the result, I find it easier to understand when I can see it.  But you do need to use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 or find the equivalent GIS algorithm for determining whether the point is in the polygon.

Comment: This search on gis.stackexchange.com  might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgis.stackexchange.com+point+in+polygon